# How does Instruments collect data from iOS without DTrace being available?

Tags: ios, xcode-instruments, dtrace

I am trying to understand the inner workings of XCode's Instruments. On MacOS, it can rely on DTrace to gather all kinds of profiling data. On iOS, it is also capable of lots of things, but I have read repeatedly that DTrace has not been ported to iOS.

So how does that work?

The Apple documentation on DTrace isn't telling me much about the inner workings here. I have noticed, however, that when profiling my own App from XCode using Instruments, XCode seems to build it differently. Could that mean it links some standalone DTrace providers with my code?

Thanks in advance!

/e: I would bounty this question with my ENTIRE 6 REPUTATION POINTS if only i could...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For iOS apps running inside the Simulator, obviously the Simulator is a Mac OS X program, so it can use DTrace to monitor everything the Simulator does.

For iOS apps running on an iPhone, I agree the documentation provides little insight into what's happening. It's probably either loading monitoring code into the target process on iOS (either by adding the code at compile time or by linking it in at runtime) or there is an "traditional debugger" running on iOS against the target process to implement the tracing. Those are pretty much the only options if there is no kernel-level support for using DTrace.

I've never used Instruments, but the main thing that jumps out at me is that they're able to collect seemingly-OS-level statistics about I/O, which would not normally be measurable without DTrace. I'm not sure because I haven't used it, but it's possible these statistics are only tracking I/O from easy-to-detect entrypoints (ie I/O-related syscalls from the specific target process), or that there are other iOS-specific statistic sources which are published by the OS. For instance, many system statistics can be gotten from Mac OS X by calling [`sysctl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sysctl.8.html). Depending on what statistics are actually being collected, Instruments could just be using simple counters like these to do most of the work.

If you're really determined to find the answer, it would be a fun DTrace challenge to figure this problem out by DTracing Instruments itself. Good luck :-)